# Error al convertir json a arreglo

Tags: javascript

Quiero convertir la variable `a` a arreglo pero sale error, como lo soluciono?

```js
function minSum(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  arr = Object.values(arr);
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  var j = arr.length - 1;
  var suma = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1 / 2; i++) {
    suma = suma + arr[i] * arr[j];
    j--;
  }
}
var a = {
  2,
  6,
  10,
  26,
  3,
  24
};
minSum(a);
```

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo el concepto de objeto. Responde tu mismo, la variable "a" que estas definiendo, ¿estás seguro que estas inicializandola correctamente?

Comment: La sintaxis que usas para definir `a` es inválida. Los objetos se definen con `propiedad: valor`, por ejemplo, `var a = {foo: 1, bar: 2}`.

Comment: sustituye las llaves por corchetes: `var a=[1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura de un objeto es:

`{ clave: valor }` o `{ key : value }` ( inglés), ejemplo => `{ nombre : 'Eduardo' }`

```js
var arr = obj => Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);


var o = { n1: 2, 
          n2: 4, 
          n3: 6 };

console.log(arr(o));
```

```
Object.values()
```

Devuelve cada valor de cada clave del objeto en un array, por lo cual sólo aplicas reduce y los sumas todos.

Answer (score 1):

Los objetos necesitan un nombre o en su defecto un número de posición para poder trabajar con ellos:

```js
function minSum(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  arr = Object.values(arr);
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  var j = arr.length - 1;
  var suma = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1 / 2; i++) {
    suma = suma + arr[i] * arr[j];
    j--;
  }
}
var a = {
 0:2,
  1:6,
  2:10,
  3:26,
  4:3,
  5:24
};
minSum(a);
```